# How can I prevent sharing Cookies on subdomains

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, cookies, jwt

Since 2 days I'm trying to prevent cookie sharing between subdomains. When I login on 1 specific sub(domain), including the first-level domain,it will also set the cookie directly to other sub(domains).

I want to separate the login process for these sub(domains).

My ConfigureServices method has the cookie settings as follows:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/token";
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true; 
    options.Cookie.Name = "AuthCookie";
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
})
```

I tried several options like `options.Cookie.Domain = "mydomain.com"` , `options.Cookie.Domain = ""` without the leading `.`, but I''ve still no success.

Comment: You can't set a cookie on the root domain `example.com` and not expect to see it on the subdomains `app.example.com`. You need to serve the app on a subdomain `www.example.com` then it won't be shared with another subdomain `app2.example.com`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#define_where_cookies_are_sent

Comment: See this for mitigation options: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Types_of_attacks#session_fixation

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, by default the  `app.example.com` and the `www.example.com` will be consider as the same site.

This is browser default behavior, but there is the Public Suffixes List which slightly changes this validation behavior.

The Public Suffixes List was created for browsers to change their same-site validation behavior.

The browser will determine if a particular URL is of this type according to this list.

If you want, you could submit your domain to this list.

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://publicsuffix.org/learn/).